# error the operation could'nt be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, ios5, sharekit

My app is working fine in both simulator and the device with ios6. But when i use the app in the ios5, i am able to login into facebook and go to the facebook app. However, when the app is about to post, it is not able to do but pops up " error the operation could'nt be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)". I have already checked the bundle id and the settings. Not sure how to solve the error. I am using sharekit to integrate the sharing

Need some help.

Comment: any help? anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Print the error's userInfo. It should give you a more detail explanation for why it's failing.